# Have different line-height between input and output area

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a terminal shell like page.

See my code at jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/paopaomj/qGw4Q/9/

The input line seems have more line-height then the outputs.
Try it and type something press some enters you'll know what I mean.

Thanks.

html:

```
<body>
<div id="output"></div>
<div id="input"> 
    root@host
    <input type="text" id="command" />
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$("#command").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        submit();
    }
});

var submit = function () {
    var commandEl = document.getElementById("command");
    var command = commandEl.value;
    var outputel = document.getElementById("output");
    var new_row = document.createElement("div");
    new_row.innerHTML = "root@host " + command;
    outputel.appendChild(new_row);
    commandEl.value="";
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The input got some padding. Add

```
padding:0px; 
margin-left:-1px;
```

to the input css

Comment: Thank you for your answering, but this seems dosen't sovle the problem,press enter, you'll see the input line still more far from the outputs.

Comment: Its solve the line-height problem, but not the problem that the input is more far to right. I'll see if I can find a solution to the problem

Comment: Thanks! This solved another problem. But I mean.. see this picture: http://goo.gl/oynlO1  I mean the red distance is longer than the blue ones. Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

OK.
I got it sovled finally by setting margin=0 for input field, margin-top=0 for iutput div, and margin-bottom=0 for output div:

```
#output { margin-bottom: 0px; background-color: #000000; }
#input { margin-top: 0px; background-color: #000000; }

input {
    border: 0;
    background: #000000;
    color: #00FF00;
    outline: none;
    font-family:'Rosario', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: -0.1px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Thanks for Johan's help!